# insufficient privileges for Scott user in Oracle for creating table

Tags: oracle11g

I installed Oracle 11g and I am trying to CREATE TABLESPACE using user 'Scott' but I am getting "insufficient privileges". What should I do ? I am connected to SQL Developer using 'Scott' user.

Comment: You can't create a tablespace as a regular user. And you shouldn't. What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you think you need (another) tablespace?

Comment: I want to install Oracle service Registry and running the script is a requirement for that according to official documentation. Which user should I use then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do `CREATE TABLESPACE` without `SYSTEM` privilege. It is a prerequisite.

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7003.htm#i2063185) -

> You must have the CREATE TABLESPACE system privilege.

Comment: so what user and pass should i use then ?

Comment: User is mentioned above, `system` privilege. And, obviously I won't  be knowing your system's password. Talk to your `DBA`.